# Как заблокировать выбор select через js в другом селекте

Tags: javascript

```
<select class="form-control ship-input-dark input-sm" name="color">
     <option value="1">Из белой</option>
     <option value="2">Из серой</option>
     <option value="3">Из зеленной</option>
     <option value="4">Из желтой</option>
     <option value="5">Из оранжевой</option>
     <option value="6">Из красной</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control ship-input-dark input-sm" name="colors">
     <option value="2">В серую</option>
     <option value="3">В зеленную</option>
     <option value="4">В желтую</option>
     <option value="5">В оранжевую</option>
     <option value="6">В красную</option>
     <option value="7">В фиолетовую</option>
</select>
```

Имеется 2 селекта. Принцип такой: если выбрали 1 пункт в 1 селекте, во втором ничего не блокировалось, а при выборе 2 пункта в первом селекте блокировался во втором силекте 1 пункт, т.е. чтоб нельзя было переконвертировать энергию "из серой в серую" и так далее.
Буду очень благодарен.

**Обновление**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[name="color"]').on("change", function() {
        var $target = $('[name="colors"]');
        var thisValue = $(this).val();
        $target.val('0');
        $target.find('option').prop('disabled', false).show();
        for (var i = 1; i < thisValue; i++) {
            $target.find('[value="' + (i + 1) + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Посмотри, что-то получилось, нормальный или быдло код как говорят? )

( http://jsfiddle.net/nwpju4ek/3/ )

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Вы уверены преобразовать x белой в x серой');">
```

Как это вставлять через js в эту же функцию? А то что-то ломается сразу. Что между ' '?

Comment: @dimas, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @dimas, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так?

```
$('[name="color"]').change(function(){
   var $target = $('[name="colors"]');
   var thisValue = $(this).val();
   $target.val('0');
   $target.find('option').prop('disabled', false).show();
   $target.find('[value="' + thisValue + '"]').prop('disabled',true).hide();
});
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/nwpju4ek/1/ )

В фиддле же работает, если у вас бутстрап, вероятнее всего нужно "переиничивать кастомный селект" после каждой манипуляции с "options". И да что говорит консоль, попробуйте ввести туда: `$('[name="colors"]').html();`

Comment: Я имел ввиду, выберите "Из серой" и покажите `$('[name="colors"]').html();`.

Comment: Обновил вопрос